# How to add Alexa's custom skills to Alexa Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit

I have set up prototype of the Alexa (AVS) on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B as it was defined at https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/set-up-raspberry-pi.html, which means that AVS is now running on my Raspberry Pi. 
In addition to this, I have created my custom skill with AWS Lambda, and have already tested it on simulator provided on the Test page. However, I could not test it on my Raspberry, Alexa which is on my Raspberry can not find the custom skill I created. Instead of my custom skills, it suggests other skills with related name. Is there any instructions on how to add my skills to the prototype of Alexa on Raspberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if your skill is in the development** and not yet live on any skill store here are a few things you can do :

1. Make sure that the account you are using to create the skill on developer console is the same account that is being used for the Rasberry Pi AVS access. If not you will need to add the account on raspberry Pi as the beta tester of the skill you have built. Please see https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/skills-beta-testing-for-alexa-skills.html.
2. If it doesn't help, go to testing tab of your skill in the developer console. Try disabling and enabling the testing for the skill. It is mostly in the case if you have changed the invocation name of the skill recently.

**If your skill is Live in the Skill store**, please make sure that locale you are using the AVS on raspberry Pi, is the same in which the skill has been published.

Comment: The skill is in development. I am new to the Alexa Skills, so after the official tutorial in amazon i created a skill and a handler in AWS Lambda, so I just wanted to check if everything works. In the simulator provided on the Test page it works great, so the next thing was to check if it is ok in Raspberry, but I don't think that I can use beta testing because of **"The skill must be ready for submission before beta testing can be enabled."** this rule.

Comment: You can use the beta testing mate. Just make sure you fill some details on the Distribution tab. If you need to know what all fields are missing in order to enable beta testing, you can use a trick. Click on Certification tab, on completion of validation it will list all the fixes you need to make.